# Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm  having this strange issue when deleting object from mongodb. I'm using mongoid as orm. Mongod service is up and running. I can access data, like `SomeModel.all.count` and that returns me value. But when i try to do `SomeModel.destroy_all` that gives me following error.

I'm using rails4, mongoid4, moped 2.0.beta2

Tell me what else data should i provide.

Comment: Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like you are running out of sockets, try raising the file descriptor limits for both mongod and for the application:

`ulimit -n 2048`